# Does edge weight of a undirected weighted graph must be a metric?

Tags: graph-theory

In a undirected weighted graph, each edge is assigned with a weight $w: E\rightarrow R$. Does $w(\cdot)$ must be a metric ? That is, $w$ satisfies the following three conditions

(1) $w(x, y) > 0 $ for any edges pair $x$ and $y$;

(2) $w(x, y) = w(y, x)$;

(3) $w(x, y) + w(y, z) \geq w(x, z)$.

Comment: It obviously satisfies the second, if the graph is undirected.  Not the others, though.

Comment: (1) No weights on a graph can be negative too, this is helpful in solving certain problems.
(2) If there are no multiple edges or directed edges, then this always holds.
(3) This is almost never true.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's obvious that $w$ cannot be a metric in general, because $w(x,y)$ is *undefined* if $(x,y)$ is not an edge. But:

Suppose $(V,E)$ is a connected undirected graph and $w(x,y)>0$ for every $(x,y)\in E$ with $x\ne y$; if edges of the form $(x,x)$ are allowed, assume $w(x,x)=0$ whenever $(x,x)\in E$. For $x,y\in V$ define $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$ and otherwise say $d(x,y)$ is the infimum of $\sum w(x_j,x_{j-1})$ over all paths $x=x_0,\dots, x_n=y$ (such that each $(x_j,x_{j-1})$ is an edge). Then it's easy to show $d$ is a metric. (Here I'm assuming that "undirected" means that if $(x,y)\in E$ then $(y,x)\in E$ and $w(y,x)=w(x,y)$.)

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't have to be a metric.

I haven't found a complete and fully explicit definition of a weighted graph anywhere, but I've found several informal descriptions of weighted graphs, and none of them say that the weight function has to be a metric.

In particular, none of the descriptions I've found say that the weight function has to satisfy the triangle inequality $w(x, y) + w(y, z) \geq w(x, z)$. For example, [these lecture notes by William D McQuain of Virginia Tech](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs3114/Fall10/Notes/T22.WeightedGraphs.pdf) show a weighted graph which includes three vertices $b$, $h$ and $i$, such that $w(b,h) = 5$ and $w(h,i) = 15$, but $w(b,i) = 25$.